# How to amp-img Align Right

Tags: amp-html, amp-img

Simple Question - I'm trying AMP (Accelerated Mobile Pages), but unable to get the image aligned to the right of the text.

```
<amp-img align="right" width="250" height="250" src="../images/image1.png"></amp-img>
```

What am I missing here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by simply putting it into a 1-tr * 1-td table which itself is right aligned:

```
<table border='1' align='right'><tr><td>
<amp-img width="250" height="250" src="../images/testimage.jpg"></amp-img>
</table>
```

Same can be achieved by putting it in a `<div>` or `<span>` class which has `align:right` property